# Snap.svg animation stop() doesn't stop animation

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, snap.svg

I am attempting a simple animation along a path that stops when the element reaches the window bounds. Here is some sample code:

```
var s = Snap("#bouncy");

var ball = s.circle(100, 100, 10);
var mypath = getLinearPath({x: 300, y: 300}, {x: 300, y: -1000});

var windowBBox = s.getBBox();

function animateAlongPath(path, element, start, dur) {
    var len = Snap.path.getTotalLength(path);
    console.log(element);
    ball.current_anim = Snap.animate(start, len, function (value) {
        var movePoint = Snap.path.getPointAtLength(path, value);
        var ballBounds = element.node.getBoundingClientRect();

        if (Snap.path.isPointInsideBBox(windowBBox, movePoint.x, movePoint.y)) {
            console.log("moving to ", movePoint);
            var t = new Snap.Matrix();
            t.translate(movePoint.x, movePoint.y);
            element.transform(t);
        } else {
            console.log("stopping");
            this.stop();
            element.stop();
            ball.current_anim.stop();
        }
    }, dur);
};

function getLinearPath(start, end) {
    var p;
    p = s.path("M " + start.x + " " + start.y + " L " + end.x + " " + end.y);
    return p
};

animateAlongPath(mypath, ball, 0, 1000);
```

I am simply trying to stop the animation when the ball reaches the top of the window frame. However, when stop() is called (either on the animation handle or the element), I continue to get callbacks until the browser freezes up.

How can I cancel the animation and prevent future callbacks?

Comment: Possible to put it on a jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 1):

I read source of Snap.svg, I found anim.stop calls own callback function. So calling stop method at animation callback makes infinite loops.

To solve this problem you can define temporary variable to block infinite loops like this.

```
var s = Snap("#bouncy");

var ball = s.circle(100, 100, 10);
var mypath = getLinearPath({x: 300, y: 300}, {x: 300, y: -1000});

var windowBBox = s.getBBox();

function animateAlongPath(path, element, start, dur) {
    var len = Snap.path.getTotalLength(path);
    console.log(element);
    ball.current_anim = Snap.animate(start, len, function (value) {
        var movePoint = Snap.path.getPointAtLength(path, value);
        var ballBounds = element.node.getBoundingClientRect();

        if (Snap.path.isPointInsideBBox(windowBBox, movePoint.x, movePoint.y)) {
            console.log("moving to ", movePoint);
            var t = new Snap.Matrix();
            t.translate(movePoint.x, movePoint.y);
            element.transform(t);
        } else {
            console.log("stopping");
            //this.stop();
            //element.stop();

            //NOTE: ball.current_anim.stop calls ball.current_anim
            var anim = ball.current_anim;
            delete ball.current_anim;
            if(anim){anim.stop();}
        }
    }, dur);
};

function getLinearPath(start, end) {
    var p;
    p = s.path("M " + start.x + " " + start.y + " L " + end.x + " " + end.y);
    return p
};

animateAlongPath(mypath, ball, 0, 1000);
```